# Get authors list and sort them by recent posts

Tags: wp-query, author, sort

I have a authors list and its sorted in the alphabetical order. The query for it is here

```
$user_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    array( 'who' => 'authors' ),
    'has_published_posts' => array('post'),
    'number'    => 4,
);

$authors = new WP_User_Query( $user_args );
```

I need to change this list of authors to sort by ones with most recent posts first. How can that be done?

Comment: You could either 1) write some SQL instead, to join wp_users against wp_posts and use group by / max to get the most recent post date and time to sort against 2) track the last post date for each user in user meta, keeping it up to date with hooks, and sort on that. There are probably more options too. The first is simpler to set up and maintain but could be more expensive to query so should definitely be cached as a transient.

Comment: @Rup I was thinking of fetching the top 4 recent posts first and then fetching the authors of those posts. Will this be okay and less expensive?

Comment: Possibly? I'm not sure on how query costs compare without trying them. Yes, that would work provided that you only want the four most recent users, and that the four most recent articles are generally written by different users.

Comment: @Rup Yeah will need to put a uniqueness of author on the recent posts. Can you post your solution using SQL?